# problem: Restarting linux programs and menus

Tags: xubuntu

I use Xubuntu 14.04.1 on my PC. I don't know why but sometimes I turn on PC and see all menus and settings have returned to default settings, for example, wallpaper, language settings or taskbar menu. If I used Windows, I could say it may be a virus, but here I have no idea.

By the way, I have installed this distribution of Linux on another PC which has exactly the same configuration and it has no problem.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score -1):

May be your PC have a bad BIOS battery and when You halt and then power on PC, BIOS time reseting?